# Play 2.4.x -- are there any tools to help create well formatted HTML and XML files?

Tags: html, xml, playframework-2.0

Play has an excellent template engine (@twirl) and when working with it it is easy to break out repetitive chunks of code into sub-templates.

The engine however is particularly notorious for adding bank lines which is very apparent in tight loops (small templates) -- sometimes I get 4 or 5 bank lines just for a template that is supposed to add a single element.

It would be nice of there were a "suppress blank lines" option in the template engine or some markers we could place int eh code to indicate "this line doesn't count towards the output" etc...

Is there any standard means of placing the output of these sub-templates back into the overall mix such that indenting is maintained?

Is there any standard/normal/built-in means of reformatting the output on the fly such that is it "nicely" formatted -- what most editors call pretty or beautified code?

Please note this is NOT a question about well-formed code -- that is easy and the machines do not care one bit (ahem) about tabs, scopes, indents or line returns.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in option, you can use some third-party Java lib that prettifies the HTML code i.e. [Google's HTML Compressor](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/).

There is also [implementation available for Play 2.x in form of filter](https://github.com/mohiva/play-html-compressor)  available. Check if it meets your needs.